# How can I catch a 404?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-handling, http-status-code-404

I have the following code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "HEAD";
request.Credentials = MyCredentialCache;

try
{
    request.GetResponse();
}
catch
{
}
```

How can I catch a specific 404 error? The WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError can only detect that an error occurred, but not give the exact code of the error.

For example:

```
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status != WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Is just not useful enough... the protocol exception could be 401, 503, 403, anything really.

Comment: **NNNOOOOOOOOOOOOO!**  Don't catch `System.Exception`, and don't depend on the exception text in your handler!

Comment: Don't use `throw ex`, you'll generate a new exception with an empty call stack. Just use `throw`.

Comment: I've always found this to be frustrating, myself.  An exception shouldn't be thrown if you get a well-formed response, and a protocol error message is definitely well-formed.  The class should allow the user to interpret the results and act accordingly.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs exceptions are no longer thrown for things like 404 in newer http clients. "Don't use exceptions for control flow" didn't seem to survive the team who built `WebRequest`

Comment: @Aaronaught: This answer is much more current: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34080863/109941

Answer (score 123, accepted):

Use the `HttpStatusCode Enumeration`, specifically `HttpStatusCode.NotFound`

Something like:

```
HttpWebResponse errorResponse = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
if (errorResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) {
  //
}
```

Where
`we` is a `WebException`.

Comment: can I get the NUMBER out somehow from the objects without making my own lookup list? I would like to have something like: int httpresponsecode = HttpStatusCode.ToInt() or similar so I get 404

Comment: @BerggreenDK you should be able to just do int httpresonsecode = **(int)** HttpStatusCode.NotFound

Comment: -1 Partial explanation of my ancient downvote: code throws NullReferenceException if, for some reason, `we.Response` is not `HttpWebResponse`. If the code wishes to assume that it will always have that type, then it should simply cast: `HttpWebResponse errorResponse = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;`. This will throw an explicit `InvalidCastException` if the impossible happens, instead of a mysterious `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: I get `An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'WebException.Response'` using this code.

Answer (score 127):

```
try
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    {
        using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            // Process the stream
        }
    }
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError &&
        ex.Response != null)
    {
        var resp = (HttpWebResponse) ex.Response;
        if (resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            // Do something
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something else
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something else
    }
}
```

Comment: lol @ being the IDisposable police and giving everyone a -1 for not wrapping the response in a using block.

Comment: It's a tough job, but _someone_ has to do it. OTOH, I almost didn't add this answer, since it might seem I was dinging everyone else to make mine the top-rated answer.

Comment: I actually upvoted, but I just noticed one thing:  There should probably be a `throw` (rethrow) at the end of your `catch`, otherwise this will just silently eat any other type of `WebException`.

Comment: @John Saunders: Why don't you have a using around your request as well?

Comment: @Joel: `WebRequest` doesn't implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: @Aaronaught: There should be a couple of "else do something else"

Comment: @John Saunders: Alrighty. Good to know. I'll have to look this up/read more about this IDisposable concept/using etc. It's a topic currently going around in our office. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

In C# 6 you can use [exception filters](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#exception-filters).

```
try
{
    var request = WebRequest.Create(uri);
    using (var response = request.GetResponse())
    using (var responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
    {
        // Process the stream
    }
}
catch(WebException ex) when ((ex.Response as HttpWebResponse)?.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
{
    // handle 404 exceptions
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    // handle other web exceptions
}
```

Comment: A very cool feature that I've been overlooking! I kept seeking methods to catch only 401 while letting others pass through to the general exception handler. This is the way to go!

Answer (score 12):

I haven't tested this, but it should work

```
try
{
    // TODO: Make request.
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
        HttpWebResponse resp = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        if (resp != null && resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
        {
            // TODO: Handle 404 error.
        }
        else
            throw;
    }
    else
        throw;
}
```

Comment: @John Saunders - I was adapting the OP's code, not optimizing it.

Comment: @John - And maybe I was only expecting them to copy/paste the `catch` block, seeing as I had the exact same code in the try as the OP.  You should really be downvoaing this question altogether because of the OP's code then.

Comment: @John we forget here is sample code.  This is case it is another way to 404, not how to use GetResponse.  -1 seems a little harsh.  +1 to Miff for answering the question.

Comment: @John  I think it is good you point it out in a comment.  The way I look at down voting is if the code given doesn't solve the problem.  Thank you for removing the down vote.

Comment: @John - Fine, I got rid of everything but the catch, happy now?

Comment: @MiffTheFox: in case you didn't notice, yes, I was happy and removed the downvote and my comments. You might want to remove your comments as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think if you catch a [WebException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx) there is some information in there that you can use to determine if it was a 404. That's the only way I know of at the moment...I'd be interested in knowing any others...

```
catch(WebException e) {
    if(e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
        var statusCode = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
        var description = (HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out this snipit. The GetResponse will throw a WebRequestException. Catch that and you can get the status code from the response.

```
try {
   // Create a web request for an invalid site. Substitute the "invalid site" strong in the Create call with a invalid name.
     HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create("invalid site");

    // Get the associated response for the above request.
     HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    myHttpWebResponse.Close();
}
catch(WebException e) {
    Console.WriteLine("This program is expected to throw WebException on successful run."+
                        "\n\nException Message :" + e.Message);
    if(e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
        Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
        Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
    }
}
catch(Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

this came from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.status.aspx

Answer (score 2):

See at [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.statuscode.aspx) about status of the response:

```
...
catch(WebException e) {
  Console.WriteLine("The following error occured : {0}",e.Status);  
}
...
```

Comment: @John Saunders - I'll be more than happy to pass it along to MSDN (where I copied the sample from...).
The purpose of this code is to show the usage of StatusCode, not be as efficient as possible.

Comment: @John Saunders - I left only the part I wanted to show, Just for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Catch the proper exception type [`WebException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.aspx):

```
try
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(String.Format("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{0}?d=404", hashe));

    using(var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        Response.Write("has avatar");
}
catch(WebException e) 
{
  if(e.Response.StatusCode == 404) 
    Response.Write("No avatar");
}
```

Comment: @John Saunders I don't debate you there, but that wasn't the question, he asked the best way to capture a 404.  My changes to his code were limited to answering the question, to make the change as simple and obvious as possible.

Comment: @John Saunders: Fixed, I suppose "if this is the most efficient" makes it apply to the question.

Comment: Just had to cast the `e.Response` as `HttpWebResponse` before gaining access to the `StatusCode`.

Answer (score 2):

For VB.NET folks browsing this, I believe we can catch the exception only if it truly is a 404.  Something like:

```
Try
    httpWebrequest.GetResponse()
Catch we As WebException When we.Response IsNot Nothing _
                              AndAlso TypeOf we.Response Is HttpWebResponse _
                              AndAlso (DirectCast(we.Response, HttpWebResponse).StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.NotFound)

    ' ...

End Try
```

Answer (score 2):

**when POST or GET data to the server using WebRequest class then the type of exception would be WebException.Below is the code for file not found exception**

```
//Create a web request with the specified URL
string path = @"http://localhost/test.xml1";
WebRequest myWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(path);

//Senda a web request and wait for response.
try
{
  WebResponse objwebResponse = myWebRequest.GetResponse();
  Stream stream= objwebResponse.GetResponseStream();
}
catch (WebException ex) {
  if (((HttpWebResponse)(ex.Response)).StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException(ex.Message);
  }
}
```