# What's wrong with my HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I dont know what are missing in my code.

If I call an 404 url my code get an exception.

```
HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(args.Url) as HttpWebRequest;
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
req.Timeout = args.TimeOut;
req.UserAgent = args.UserAgent;   
HttpWebResponse answer = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
objResult.Status =answer.StatusCode;
Stream stream = answer.GetResponseStream();
```

I get an exception on req.GetResponse()

There is the error i get back

The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

I am not suppose to received HttpStatusCode.NotFound ?

**The solution :**

```
try
      {
        HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(args.Url) as HttpWebRequest;
        req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        req.Timeout = args.TimeOut;
        req.UserAgent = args.UserAgent;       
        HttpWebResponse answer = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

        objResult.Status =answer.StatusCode;       
      }
      catch (WebException ex)
      {
        HttpWebResponse response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        objResult.Status = response.StatusCode;       
      }
```

Comment: Probably [this answer][1] here also answers your question.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949610/c-how-can-i-catch-a-404

Comment: @McKay, you can try with http://www.google.com/NotExists you will see the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HttpWebRequest` throws an exception on non-successful response statuses.
This behavior is by design.

You can get the response by catching a `WebException` and checking its `Response` property.

Comment: Good, it's work thanks. With the answer from Alaudo to I just need to cast the WebException.Response to HttpWebResponse