# Can't ignore 404 not found httpwebrequest

Tags: c#

I can't seem to be able to ignore the 404 not found.

I tried to make it add it to a text file so I can just continue with the requests but the program just closes.

```
private static readonly Thread Awesome = new Thread(Request);

private const string Url = "http://whatever/";

public static void Request() {
    try {

        const string filename = "names.txt";
        Reader.Readtext(filename);

        foreach (var names in Reader.Lastname) {

            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(Url + names);
            Console.WriteLine("Request Sent: " + Url + names);

            var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
            var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

            sr.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {
        if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
        {
            var resp = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
            if (resp != null && resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
            {
                const string filename = "error.txt";
                Writer.writetofile(filename, resp.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}

private static void Main()
{

    Awesome.Start();
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949610/how-can-i-catch-a-404

Comment: i already catched it am trying to ignore it

Comment: you are not throwing it again so the only place you can get error is while writing to the file. Make sure `Writer.writetofile` does not fail.

Comment: move your try catch insde your foreach loop

Answer (score 0):

```
private static readonly Thread Awesome = new Thread(Request);

private const string Url = "http://whatever/";

public static void Request() {
        const string filename = "names.txt";
        Reader.Readtext(filename);

        foreach (var names in Reader.Lastname) {

            var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(Url + names);
            Console.WriteLine("Request Sent: " + Url + names);
            try{
                var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
                var sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());

                sr.ReadToEnd();            
            }
            catch (WebException ex)
            {
                if (ex.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    var resp = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse;
                    if (resp != null && resp.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                    {
                        const string filename = "error.txt";
                        Writer.writetofile(filename, resp.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}

private static void Main()
{

    Awesome.Start();
}
```