# Request URL with HTTP or HTTPS in C#

Tags: c#, http, https, httprequest

I have two inputs for set urls, first for image and second for some site

I must to load image and site in iframe

If user set url with scheme everything is ok, the problems spears when url does not contains the scheme '**http://**' or '**https://**'

how to add right scheme to url

make a request to '**http://**' + **my_url** and check if the code if is 404 make another request to '**https://**' + **my_url**

Comment: it isn`t clear what do you want to achive. Please clarify your question

Answer (score 0):

I think this one can help you if you mean this what i think.

[How can I catch a 404?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949610/how-can-i-catch-a-404)
if there's a 404 you run the same code with and without "https" it's on you on which one you start "requesting".